# TypeError: 'get ready' called on an object that does not implement interface ServiceWorkerContainer. on expanding navigator.serviceWorker object

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, service-worker, firefox-developer-tools

`firefox version: 58.0`

Type `navigator.serviceWorker` in firefox console, and click `ServiceWorkerContainer` to expand it.

And get an error: `TypeError: 'get ready' called on an object that does not implement interface ServiceWorkerContainer.`

What does it mean? And is it a firefox bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not a bug, but it's interesting.

When the devtools tried to expand it, in addition to accessing `navigator.serviceWorker`'s own properties, it tried to access the properties of its prototype (shown in the devtools with the browser-specific `__proto__` property name). Apparently when doing that, the `this` it gave wasn't `navigator.serviceWorker` (my guess is it was the prototype object itself, e.g. `Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator.serviceWorker)`), and the implementation of the `ready` getter on the prototype expects to be called on an inheriting object (loosely, an "instance"), not the prototype itself.

You'd get the same error if you did this in the Firefox console:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator.serviceWorker).ready
```

Nothing to worry about. :-)